# I accidentally deleted multiple projects in Visual Studio by deleting a project that contained them in its directory

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, file-recovery

I was experiencing some issues with one of my python files, so wanted to create a new Python project in Visual Studio to test it. I am using Windows 10.

1. I chose to create a project from an existing file (which was one
   directory above the projects in my solution).
2. When I created the project, it included both of the project folders
   in that project.
3. Thinking this was a mistake, I deleted the project (both in visual
   studio and in file explorer) and tried to do it differently.

As result, all of the files in both of my projects were deleted, and I cannot recover them. I tried looking in the recycling bin, but had no luck.

Update: I tried checking Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files and the projects that I am now missing the files from are not there.

Is there a way to revert my PC to the memory that it had a few hours ago?

Please help me out.

Comment: There are no URGENT questions here. No question is more urgent or important than any other. If you require URGENT help, hire a contractor and pay them to provide it to you. Here, you can ask your question like everyone else, and if someone can help you they will. In addition, this site is for programming related questions, and recovering files you deleted is not a programming question. This post is more suitable for [su] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using Windows OS. There are several data recovery softwares for Windows, you just need to search the web a little bit. They might help you.

I recommend you to use GitHub or some other version control system that saves files in cloud. This way this accident won't happen again.

Comment: You are correct. I am using Windows 10. I know I should be using source control. I have looked online, and am trying a few things, but do you know of any shortcuts? I was reading something about "Windows SourceSafe Explorer."

Comment: Better yet, do you have a specific software recommendation? I have tried a few.

Comment: For source control I would use just Visual Studio and GitHub. I have no recommendation for data recovery software but quick search gave me this https://7datarecovery.com/best-recovery-apps/ I hope it helps.

Comment: I usually use SourceTree, but I was not expecting this at all. Do you know of a way to revert my memory to what it was a few hours ago? I haven't added anything of value in that time. I am looking for the Windows version of Time Machine (assuming that it is pre-setup). The backups are missing from VS 2019.

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of Window version of Time Machine. I was thinking that if you have lost your files (and maybe folders) you may try to recover deleted files with data recovery program.

Comment: I think that I got it. Here's what I used: https://www.easeus.com/ .
I thought that maybe visual studio might also have some backups (for example, when you have build errors, it typically asks if you'd like to run the last successfully build). I am sure there are other alternatives that I am missing, but it seems that I have gotten back most of my files.